# Simple Present versus Present Progressive

Tags: tense, present-tense, present-continuous

What is the correct form and why?

> Do you miss some item that is on the list?

> Are you missing some item that is on the list?

The context in this particular example
[image: Context]

Comment: "some item-**s**", not "some item".

Comment: Or the sentence could use "any item."

Comment: @Mistu4u care to explain?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, Yes and in fact, "any item" sounds more natural.

Comment: BDW, the sense you want to convey is more clear in the second example. However I can't really explain why can't I admit the first example though it looks grammatical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They really mean two different things.

- **Do you miss something on the list?**
  You *miss* something which you have lost or someone who is absent: you feel sadness at no longer having the thing or the presence. For instance, you miss your old Corvette that finally blew out its engine; or you miss your sister whom you haven't seen for several months.
- **Are you missing anything on the list?**
  You *are missing* something which you are supposed to have and thought you had but can't find. For instance, you're missing the cable you need to hook up your new printer. ... This may also be expressed with the 'something' as subject:
  Is anything on the list missing?

If what you mean to ask is whether there is something on the list your hearer doesn't have but needs, try this instead:

- Is there anything on the list you need?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Your explanation is more than satisfactory. I think I have it correct now, but here is the context to be sure http://i.imgur.com/dqXP0yy.png

Comment: @Grant It looks OK to me. I'd say "Did you find **an** item?" rather than **some**.  *Some* isn't in any way wrong, but it feels like [academic overprecision](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JPfVGotIQI).